# C++ towlower comparison with original character fails?

Tags: c++, comparison, special-characters, tolower

I have the following code in C++:

```
string StringTest = "Test";
bool OriginalWord = true;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < StringTest(); i++) {
    string Character = towlower(StringTest[i]);
    string CharacterOriginal = StringTest[i];
    if (Character != CharacterOriginal) {
        //t vs. T should trigger false, but never happens?
        //e vs. e should trigger true
        //s vs. s should trigger true 
        //t vs. t should trigger true
        OriginalWord = false;
        }
    }
```

Note that I use `towlower` instead of `tolower`.

This always results in a `OriginalWord=true` situation. However, e.g. Test should give me back `OriginalWord=false`. Because `towlower(T)` will result in t and the `CharacterOriginal = T`, which means they are not the same and thus `OriginalWord=false`?

What am I doing wrong? I guess it has to do something with the `towlower` function

Comment: That code should not even compile, because you try to initialize a `std::string` from a single character (technically a `std::wint_t`) (and other problems).

Comment: `i < StringTest()` ?

Comment: You are mixing up methods for wstring (towlower) with string methods (tolower)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, it compiles though :)

Comment: @Martze, this sounds like where my thoughts where going, but I have no idea how to fix this issue. I am quite new to C++

Comment: Which compiler do you use which compiles that code ?

Comment: @Jarod42, I use the mingw32-g++ compiler in codeblocks

Answer (score 0):

You have some trouble with type conversions, which wouldn't fly with stricter compiler flags. Please see the comments in the code fragment below:

```
string StringTest = "Test";
bool OriginalWord = true;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < StringTest.size(); i++) 
// do you mean StringTest.size() instead of StringTest()?
{
    wint_t Character = towlower(StringTest[i]);
    wint_t CharacterOriginal = StringTest[i];
// can't convert a char to a string (or const char *)
// did you meant to use wint_t instead of string?
    if (Character != CharacterOriginal) 
    {
        //t vs. T should trigger false, but never happens?
        //e vs. e should trigger true
        //s vs. s should trigger true 
        //t vs. t should trigger true
        OriginalWord = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay,
there some troubles in your code,
first:

```
string StringTest = "Test"; // you created StringTest as a single variable
 //in the next steps you use it all the time as a array, lets change that.

int count = 10;
string StringTest[count] = { "Test", "test","Test", "test","Test", "test","Test", "test","Test", "test" };

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < StringTest(); i++) // you must use the size of string so:
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++)
```

Answer (score -1):

string Character **false usage**, it must be a char Because **tolower** returns int(char) not a string.
Also to get length of string -> StringTest.**size()**;

The edited code is here!

```
string StringTest = "Test";
bool OriginalWord = true;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < StringTest.size(); i++) {
    char Character = tolower(StringTest[i]);
    char CharacterOriginal = StringTest[i];
    if (Character != CharacterOriginal) {
        OriginalWord = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not using towlower but tolower and is not an option.

Comment: then use wstring instead of string